# Using Linq to get the last N elements of a collection?

Tags: c#, linq

Given a collection, is there a way to get the last N elements of that collection?  If there isn't a method in the framework, what would be the best way to write an extension method to do this?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.takelast

Comment: As @Neo and @Ray note, `TakeLast()` is available in .Net Core 2.0 and higher and .Net Standard 2.1 and higher

Answer (score 512, accepted):

```
collection.Skip(Math.Max(0, collection.Count() - N));
```

This approach preserves item order without a dependency on any sorting, and has broad compatibility across several LINQ providers.

It is important to take care not to call `Skip` with a negative number. Some providers, such as the Entity Framework, will produce an ArgumentException when presented with a negative argument. The call to `Math.Max` avoids this neatly.

The class below has all of the essentials for extension methods, which are: a static class, a static method, and use of the `this` keyword.

```
public static class MiscExtensions
{
    // Ex: collection.TakeLast(5);
    public static IEnumerable<T> TakeLast<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int N)
    {
        return source.Skip(Math.Max(0, source.Count() - N));
    }
}
```

**A brief note on performance:**

Because the call to `Count()` can cause enumeration of certain data structures, this approach has the risk of causing two passes over the data. This isn't really a problem with most enumerables; in fact, optimizations exist already for Lists, Arrays, and even EF queries to evaluate the `Count()` operation in O(1) time.

If, however, you must use a forward-only enumerable and would like to avoid making two passes, consider a one-pass algorithm like [Lasse V. Karlsen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3453310/404854) or [Mark Byers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3453340/404854) describe. Both of these approaches use a temporary buffer to hold items while enumerating, which are yielded once the end of the collection is found.

Comment: +1, as this works in Linq to Entities/SQL. I'm guessing it's also more performant in Linq to Objects than James Curran's strategy.

Comment: Depends on the nature of collection.  Count() might be O(N).

Comment: @James: Absolutely correct. If dealing strictly with IEnumerable collections, this could be a two-pass query. I'd be very interested in seeing a guaranteed 1-pass algorithm. It might be useful.

Comment: I would make two such methods, one for `IQueryable<T>`, and one for `IEnumerable<T>`, using different methods. I suspect this method, and the double-reverse method, would both run nicely on Linq-To-SQL and Linq-To-Entities.

Comment: Did some benchmarks. It turns out LINQ to Objects performs some optimizations based on the type of collection you're using. Using arrays, `List`s, and `LinkedList`s, James's solution tends to be faster, though not by an order of magnitude. If the IEnumerable is calculated (via Enumerable.Range, e.g.), James's solution takes longer. I can't think of any way to guarantee a single pass without either knowing something about the implementation or copying values to a different data structure.

Comment: @Mark: The Reverse method is not supported by LINQ to SQL or LINQ to Entities. This strategy, on the other hand, produces a `Select ... where row_number between ... and ...` query in LINQ to SQL, which is probably pretty quick. Of course, if you know what data type you're dealing with, you could do an OrderBy, Take, and OrderByDescending, which might be quicker.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior: Nice. Thanks for the footwork! How large were the collections you did your benchmarks in?

Comment: @kbrimington: 1000000 elements in the collection, and I took the last 10000 elements from it, ten times. Any more, and I started running into memory issues which make the tests unreliable. @Mark: That makes sense, assuming you know what you're ordering by (which is a reasonable assumption since you can't Take in Linq to SQL or Entities without first performing OrderBy). I was actually thinking of that and edited my comment before I saw your response.

Comment: @RedFilter - Fair enough. I suppose my paging habits leaked out here. Thanks for your keen eye.

Comment: @kbrimington No problem, just wanted to make sure I understood what was going on here...

Comment: The Math.Max(), and hence the Count(), seems unnecessary as well. According to documentation, Skip() returns the entire array if the amount is <= 0.

Comment: @AndrewMao, not so. In Entity Framework 4, a negative value for Skip results in an `ArgumentException`.

Comment: No ArgumentException anywhere on this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985.aspx; also, I use negative values for `Skip` all the time. If .NET 4.0/4.5 is not 'Entity Framework 4', then what is it?

Comment: @AndrewMao - Then kindly ask Microsoft to correct their documentation. The code throws an exception when using Entity Framework. It is important not to confuse general LINQ-to-objects with the Entity Framework. They work together; however, they are not the same thing.

Comment: use    collection.OrderByDescending(i => i.ID)).Take(N)

Comment: @YanVeilleux, Thanks for your suggestion, but it is incorrect. Firstly, your proposal assumes that an `ID` property is available at all. Secondly, it changes the order of the elements, which may be an undesirable side effect. Lastly, your proposal has longer run time, being O(n log n) instead of O(n).

Comment: You are missing a "this" before the "source" parameter type for this to truly be an extension method.

Comment: You can fix the multiple enumeration problem with this: var enumerated = source as IList<T> ?? source.ToList();
return enumerated.Skip(Math.Max(0, enumerated.Count() - n));

Comment: @DharmaTurtle, Interesting perspective. Perhaps materializing the query into a list would be appropriate for in-memory collections where each entity is expensive to materialize; however, I would discourage this idea for L2S or EF queries, as it would cause more entities to be materialized than are necessary. Also, constructing a list, while O(N), is more expensive than merely iterating across most collections.

Answer (score 75):

```
coll.Reverse().Take(N).Reverse().ToList();


public static IEnumerable<T> TakeLast<T>(this IEnumerable<T> coll, int N)
{
    return coll.Reverse().Take(N).Reverse();
}
```

UPDATE: To address clintp's problem:  a) Using the TakeLast() method I defined above solves the problem, but if you really want the do it without the extra method, then you just have to recognize that while Enumerable.Reverse() can be used as an extension method, you aren't required to use it that way:

```
List<string> mystring = new List<string>() { "one", "two", "three" }; 
mystring = Enumerable.Reverse(mystring).Take(2).Reverse().ToList();
```

Comment: The problem I have with this, is if I say:                  `List<string> mystring = new List<string>() { "one", "two", "three" }; mystring = mystring.Reverse().Take(2).Reverse();`  I get a compiler error because .Reverse() returns void and the compiler chooses that method instead of the Linq one that returns an IEnumerable.  Suggestions?

Comment: You can solve this problem by explicitly casting mystring to IEnumerable<String>:
    ((IEnumerable<String>)mystring).Reverse().Take(2).Reverse()

Comment: Easy and simple enough but requires reversing the order two times completely. This can be the best way

Comment: I like it in addition to the accepted answer from kbrimington. If you do not care about the order after you have the last `N` records you can skip the second `Reverse`.

Comment: @shashwat It doesn't reverse the order twice "completely".  The second reversal only applies to the collection of N items.  Further, depending how Reverse() is implemented the first call to it may only reverse N items.  (The .NET 4.0 implementation will copy the collection to an array, and index backward off it)

Answer (score 68):

.NET Core 2.0+ provides the LINQ method `TakeLast()`:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.takelast

*example*:

```
Enumerable
    .Range(1, 10)
    .TakeLast(3) // <--- takes last 3 items
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(i => System.Console.WriteLine(i))

// outputs:
// 8
// 9
// 10
```

Comment: I'm using :NET Standard 2.0 and I don't have it available. What's wrong? :(

Comment: @SuperJMN Although you may be referencing .net standard 2.0 libraries, you might not be targeting the correct version of dotnet core in your project. This method is not available for v1.x (`netcoreapp1.x`) but only for v2.0 & v2.1 of dotnetcore (`netcoreapp2.x`). 

It's possible you maybe targeting the full framework (e.g. `net472`) which is also unsupported. 

(.net standard libs can be used by any of the above but may only expose certain APIs specific to a target framework. see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks)

Comment: These needs to be higher up now. No need to re-invent the wheel

Comment: @SuperJMN correct. This is NOT available in Standard 2.0. It is however in Standard 2.1

Answer (score 55):

**Note**: I missed your question title which said **Using Linq**, so my answer does not in fact use Linq.

If you want to avoid caching a non-lazy copy of the entire collection, you could write a simple method that does it using a linked list.

The following method will add each value it finds in the original collection into a linked list, and trim the linked list down to the number of items required. Since it keeps the linked list trimmed to this number of items the entire time through iterating through the collection, it will only keep a copy of at most N items from the original collection.

It does not require you to know the number of items in the original collection, nor iterate over it more than once.

Usage:

```
IEnumerable<int> sequence = Enumerable.Range(1, 10000);
IEnumerable<int> last10 = sequence.TakeLast(10);
...
```

Extension method:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> TakeLast<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection,
        int n)
    {
        if (collection == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(collection));
        if (n < 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(n), $"{nameof(n)} must be 0 or greater");

        LinkedList<T> temp = new LinkedList<T>();

        foreach (var value in collection)
        {
            temp.AddLast(value);
            if (temp.Count > n)
                temp.RemoveFirst();
        }

        return temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: I still think you have a good, valid answer even if it isn't technically using Linq, so I still give you a +1 :)

Comment: I think its the only solution that doesn't cause the source enumerator to be run through twice (or more), and doesn't force the materialization of the enumeration, so in most applications I would say it would be much more efficient in terms of memory and speed.

Comment: @Sprotty I think you would have to test this dependent on your collection. However, the tests I did with very large numbers of int collections the Skip always came out much faster (~10x faster).

Comment: It's worth noting that .NET Core added a `TakeLast` method, which uses a Queue instead of a LinkedList

Answer (score 33):

Here's a method that works on any enumerable but uses only O(N) temporary storage:

```
public static class TakeLastExtension
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> TakeLast<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int takeCount)
    {
        if (source == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("source"); }
        if (takeCount < 0) { throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("takeCount", "must not be negative"); }
        if (takeCount == 0) { yield break; }

        T[] result = new T[takeCount];
        int i = 0;

        int sourceCount = 0;
        foreach (T element in source)
        {
            result[i] = element;
            i = (i + 1) % takeCount;
            sourceCount++;
        }

        if (sourceCount < takeCount)
        {
            takeCount = sourceCount;
            i = 0;
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < takeCount; ++j)
        {
            yield return result[(i + j) % takeCount];
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
List<int> l = new List<int> {4, 6, 3, 6, 2, 5, 7};
List<int> lastElements = l.TakeLast(3).ToList();
```

It works by using a ring buffer of size N to store the elements as it sees them, overwriting old elements with new ones. When the end of the enumerable is reached the ring buffer contains the last N elements.

Comment: +1: This should have better performance than mine, but you should make sure it does the right thing when the collection contains fewer elements than `n`.

Comment: Well, most of the time I assume people will take care when copying code from SO for production use to add such things themselves, it might not be a problem. If you're going to add it, consider checking the collection variable for null as well. Otherwise, excellent solution :) I was considering using a ring-buffer myself, because a linked list will add GC-pressure, but it's been a while since I did one and I didn't want to hassle with test-code to figure out if I did it right. I must say I'm falling in love with LINQPad though :) http://www.linqpad.net/

Comment: A possible optimization would be to check if the enumerable implemented IList, and use the trivial solution if it does. The temporary storage approach would then only be needed for truely 'streaming' IEnumerables

Comment: trivial nit-pick: your arguments to ArgumentOutOfRangeException are in the wrong order (R# says)

Answer (score 12):

I am surprised that no one has mentioned it, but SkipWhile does have a method that [uses the element's index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549288).

```
public static IEnumerable<T> TakeLastN<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int n)
{
    if (source == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("Source cannot be null");

    int goldenIndex = source.Count() - n;
    return source.SkipWhile((val, index) => index < goldenIndex);
}

//Or if you like them one-liners (in the spirit of the current accepted answer);
//However, this is most likely impractical due to the repeated calculations
collection.SkipWhile((val, index) => index < collection.Count() - N)
```

The only perceivable benefit that this solution presents over others is that you can have the option to add in a predicate to make a more powerful and efficient LINQ query, instead of having two separate operations that traverse the IEnumerable twice.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> FilterLastN<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int n, Predicate<T> pred)
{
    int goldenIndex = source.Count() - n;
    return source.SkipWhile((val, index) => index < goldenIndex && pred(val));
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Use EnumerableEx.TakeLast in RX's System.Interactive assembly. It's an O(N) implementation like @Mark's, but it uses a queue rather than a ring-buffer construct (and dequeues items when it reaches buffer capacity).

(NB: This is the IEnumerable version - not the IObservable version, though the implementation of the two is pretty much identical)

Comment: This is the best answer. Don't roll your own if there is a suitable library that does the job and the RX team is high quality.

Comment: If you are going with this, install it from Nuget - http://www.nuget.org/packages/Ix-Async/

Comment: Isn't C# `Queue<T>` implemented using a [circular buffer](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/generic/queue.cs) ?

Comment: @tigrou . no, it is not circular

Comment: [Then documentation must be lying](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/generic/queue.cs,22)

Answer (score 7):

If you are dealing with a collection with a key (e.g. entries from a database) a quick (i.e. faster than the selected answer) solution would be

```
collection.OrderByDescending(c => c.Key).Take(3).OrderBy(c => c.Key);
```

Comment: +1 works for me and it's easy to read, i have a small number of objects in my list

Answer (score 5):

If you don't mind dipping into Rx as part of the monad, you can use `TakeLast`:

```
IEnumerable<int> source = Enumerable.Range(1, 10000);

IEnumerable<int> lastThree = source.AsObservable().TakeLast(3).AsEnumerable();
```

Comment: You don't need AsObservable() if you reference RX's System.Interactive instead of System.Reactive (see my answer)

Answer (score 4):

I tried to combine efficiency and simplicity and end up with this :

```
public static IEnumerable<T> TakeLast<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int count)
{
    if (source == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("source"); }

    Queue<T> lastElements = new Queue<T>();
    foreach (T element in source)
    {
        lastElements.Enqueue(element);
        if (lastElements.Count > count)
        {
            lastElements.Dequeue();
        }
    }

    return lastElements;
}
```

About 
performance : In C#, `Queue<T>` is implemented using a [circular buffer](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/generic/queue.cs) so there is no object instantiation done each loop (only when the queue is growing up). I did not set queue capacity (using dedicated constructor) because someone might call this extension with `count = int.MaxValue` . For extra performance you might check if source implement `IList<T>` and if yes, directly extract the last values using array indexes.

Answer (score 3):

If using a third-party library is an option, [MoreLinq](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) defines `TakeLast()` which does exactly this.

Comment: Project moved to github: [here](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ)

Answer (score 2):

My solution is based on ranges, introduced in C# version 8.

```cs
        public static IEnumerable<T> TakeLast<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int N)
        {
            return source.ToArray()[(source.Count()-N)..];
        }
```

After running a benchmark with most rated solutions (and my humbly proposed solution):

```cs
    public static class TakeLastExtension
    {
        public static IEnumerable<T> TakeLastMarkByers<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int takeCount)
        {
            if (source == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("source"); }
            if (takeCount < 0) { throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("takeCount", "must not be negative"); }
            if (takeCount == 0) { yield break; }

            T[] result = new T[takeCount];
            int i = 0;

            int sourceCount = 0;
            foreach (T element in source)
            {
                result[i] = element;
                i = (i + 1) % takeCount;
                sourceCount++;
            }

            if (sourceCount < takeCount)
            {
                takeCount = sourceCount;
                i = 0;
            }

            for (int j = 0; j < takeCount; ++j)
            {
                yield return result[(i + j) % takeCount];
            }
        }

        public static IEnumerable<T> TakeLastKbrimington<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int N)
        {
            return source.Skip(Math.Max(0, source.Count() - N));
        }

        public static IEnumerable<T> TakeLastJamesCurran<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int N)
        {
            return source.Reverse().Take(N).Reverse();
        }

        public static IEnumerable<T> TakeLastAlex<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int N)
        {
            return source.ToArray()[(source.Count()-N)..];
        }
    }
```

Test

```cs
    [MemoryDiagnoser]
    public class TakeLastBenchmark
    {
        [Params(10000)]
        public int N;

        private readonly List<string> l = new();

        [GlobalSetup]
        public void Setup()
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < this.N; i++)
            {
                this.l.Add($"i");
            }
        }

        [Benchmark]
        public void Benchmark1_MarkByers()
        {
            var lastElements = l.TakeLastMarkByers(3).ToList();
        }

        [Benchmark]
        public void Benchmark2_Kbrimington()
        {
            var lastElements = l.TakeLastKbrimington(3).ToList();
        }

        [Benchmark]
        public void Benchmark3_JamesCurran()
        {
            var lastElements = l.TakeLastJamesCurran(3).ToList();
        }

        [Benchmark]
        public void Benchmark4_Alex()
        {
            var lastElements = l.TakeLastAlex(3).ToList();
        }
    }
```

Program.cs:

```cs
var summary = BenchmarkRunner.Run(typeof(TakeLastBenchmark).Assembly);
```

Command `dotnet run --project .\TestsConsole2.csproj -c Release --logBuildOutput`

The results were following:

> // * Summary *
>
> BenchmarkDotNet=v0.13.2, OS=Windows 10 (10.0.19044.1889/21H2/November2021Update)
> AMD Ryzen 5 5600X, 1 CPU, 12 logical and 6 physical cores
> .NET SDK=6.0.401
> [Host]     : .NET 6.0.9 (6.0.922.41905), X64 RyuJIT AVX2
> DefaultJob : .NET 6.0.9 (6.0.922.41905), X64 RyuJIT AVX2

| Method | N | Mean | Error | StdDev | Gen0 | Gen1 | Allocated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Benchmark1_MarkByers | 10000 | 89,390.53 ns | 1,735.464 ns | 1,704.457 ns | - | - | 248 B |
| Benchmark2_Kbrimington | 10000 | 46.15 ns | 0.410 ns | 0.363 ns | 0.0076 | - | 128 B |
| Benchmark3_JamesCurran | 10000 | 2,703.15 ns | 46.298 ns | 67.862 ns | 4.7836 | 0.0038 | 80264 B |
| Benchmark4_Alex | 10000 | 2,513.48 ns | 48.661 ns | 45.517 ns | 4.7607 | - | 80152 B |

Turns out the solution proposed by **@Kbrimington** to be the most efficient in terms of memory alloc as well as raw performance.

Answer (score 1):

It is a little inefficient to take the last N of a collection using LINQ as all the above solutions require iterating across the collection. `TakeLast(int n)` in `System.Interactive` also has this problem.

If you have a list a more efficient thing to do is slice it using the following method

```
/// Select from start to end exclusive of end using the same semantics
/// as python slice.
/// <param name="list"> the list to slice</param>
/// <param name="start">The starting index</param>
/// <param name="end">The ending index. The result does not include this index</param>
public static List<T> Slice<T>
(this IReadOnlyList<T> list, int start, int? end = null)
{
    if (end == null)
    {
        end = list.Count();
    }
     if (start < 0)
    {
        start = list.Count + start;
    }
     if (start >= 0 && end.Value > 0 && end.Value > start)
    {
        return list.GetRange(start, end.Value - start);
    }
     if (end < 0)
    {
        return list.GetRange(start, (list.Count() + end.Value) - start);
    }
     if (end == start)
    {
        return new List<T>();
    }
     throw new IndexOutOfRangeException(
        "count = " + list.Count() + 
        " start = " + start +
        " end = " + end);
}
```

with

```
public static List<T> GetRange<T>( this IReadOnlyList<T> list, int index, int count )
{
    List<T> r = new List<T>(count);
    for ( int i = 0; i < count; i++ )
    {
        int j=i + index;
        if ( j >= list.Count )
        {
            break;
        }
        r.Add(list[j]);
    }
    return r;
}
```

and some test cases

```
[Fact]
public void GetRange()
{
    IReadOnlyList<int> l = new List<int>() { 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60 };
     l
        .GetRange(2, 3)
        .ShouldAllBeEquivalentTo(new[] { 20, 30, 40 });
     l
        .GetRange(5, 10)
        .ShouldAllBeEquivalentTo(new[] { 50, 60 });

}
 [Fact]
void SliceMethodShouldWork()
{
    var list = new List<int>() { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11 };
    list.Slice(1, 4).ShouldBeEquivalentTo(new[] { 3, 5, 7 });
    list.Slice(1, -2).ShouldBeEquivalentTo(new[] { 3, 5, 7 });
    list.Slice(1, null).ShouldBeEquivalentTo(new[] { 3, 5, 7, 9, 11 });
    list.Slice(-2)
        .Should()
        .BeEquivalentTo(new[] {9, 11});
     list.Slice(-2,-1 )
        .Should()
        .BeEquivalentTo(new[] {9});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it's to late to answer this question. But if you are working with collection of type IList<> and you don't care about an order of the returned collection, then this method is working faster. I've used [Mark Byers answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3453340/2389106) and made a little changes. So now method TakeLast is:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> TakeLast<T>(IList<T> source, int takeCount)
{
    if (source == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("source"); }
    if (takeCount < 0) { throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("takeCount", "must not be negative"); }
    if (takeCount == 0) { yield break; }

    if (source.Count > takeCount)
    {
        for (int z = source.Count - 1; takeCount > 0; z--)
        {
            takeCount--;
            yield return source[z];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < source.Count; i++)
        {
            yield return source[i];
        }
    }
}
```

For test I have used **Mark Byers method and kbrimington's andswer**. This is test:

```
IList<int> test = new List<int>();
for(int i = 0; i<1000000; i++)
{
    test.Add(i);
}

Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
stopwatch.Start();

IList<int> result = TakeLast(test, 10).ToList();

stopwatch.Stop();

Stopwatch stopwatch1 = new Stopwatch();
stopwatch1.Start();

IList<int> result1 = TakeLast2(test, 10).ToList();

stopwatch1.Stop();

Stopwatch stopwatch2 = new Stopwatch();
stopwatch2.Start();

IList<int> result2 = test.Skip(Math.Max(0, test.Count - 10)).Take(10).ToList();

stopwatch2.Stop();
```

And here are results for taking 10 elements:

[image]

and for taking 1000001 elements results are:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution:

```
public static class EnumerationExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> TakeLast<T>(this IEnumerable<T> input, int count)
    {
        if (count <= 0)
            yield break;

        var inputList = input as IList<T>;

        if (inputList != null)
        {
            int last = inputList.Count;
            int first = last - count;

            if (first < 0)
                first = 0;

            for (int i = first; i < last; i++)
                yield return inputList[i];
        }
        else
        {
            // Use a ring buffer. We have to enumerate the input, and we don't know in advance how many elements it will contain.
            T[] buffer = new T[count];

            int index = 0;

            count = 0;

            foreach (T item in input)
            {
                buffer[index] = item;

                index = (index + 1) % buffer.Length;
                count++;
            }

            // The index variable now points at the next buffer entry that would be filled. If the buffer isn't completely
            // full, then there are 'count' elements preceding index. If the buffer *is* full, then index is pointing at
            // the oldest entry, which is the first one to return.
            //
            // If the buffer isn't full, which means that the enumeration has fewer than 'count' elements, we'll fix up
            // 'index' to point at the first entry to return. That's easy to do; if the buffer isn't full, then the oldest
            // entry is the first one. :-)
            //
            // We'll also set 'count' to the number of elements to be returned. It only needs adjustment if we've wrapped
            // past the end of the buffer and have enumerated more than the original count value.

            if (count < buffer.Length)
                index = 0;
            else
                count = buffer.Length;

            // Return the values in the correct order.
            while (count > 0)
            {
                yield return buffer[index];

                index = (index + 1) % buffer.Length;
                count--;
            }
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> SkipLast<T>(this IEnumerable<T> input, int count)
    {
        if (count <= 0)
            return input;
        else
            return input.SkipLastIter(count);
    }

    private static IEnumerable<T> SkipLastIter<T>(this IEnumerable<T> input, int count)
    {
        var inputList = input as IList<T>;

        if (inputList != null)
        {
            int first = 0;
            int last = inputList.Count - count;

            if (last < 0)
                last = 0;

            for (int i = first; i < last; i++)
                yield return inputList[i];
        }
        else
        {
            // Aim to leave 'count' items in the queue. If the input has fewer than 'count'
            // items, then the queue won't ever fill and we return nothing.

            Queue<T> elements = new Queue<T>();

            foreach (T item in input)
            {
                elements.Enqueue(item);

                if (elements.Count > count)
                    yield return elements.Dequeue();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code is a bit chunky, but as a drop-in reusable component, it should perform as well as it can in most scenarios, and it'll keep the code that's using it nice and concise. :-)

My `TakeLast` for non-`` IList`1 `` is based on the same ring buffer algorithm as that in the answers by @Mark Byers and @MackieChan further up. It's interesting how similar they are -- I wrote mine completely independently. Guess there's really just one way to do a ring buffer properly. :-)

Looking at @kbrimington's answer, an additional check could be added to this for `IQuerable<T>` to fall back to the approach that works well with Entity Framework -- assuming that what I have at this point does not.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly I'm not super proud of the answer, but for small collections you could use the following:

```
var lastN = collection.Reverse().Take(n).Reverse();
```

A bit hacky but it does the job ;)

Answer (score 0):

Below the real example how to take last 3 elements from a collection (array):

```
// split address by spaces into array
string[] adrParts = adr.Split(new string[] { " " },StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
// take only 3 last items in array
adrParts = adrParts.SkipWhile((value, index) => { return adrParts.Length - index > 3; }).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using This Method To Get All Range Without Error

```
 public List<T> GetTsRate( List<T> AllT,int Index,int Count)
        {
            List<T> Ts = null;
            try
            {
                Ts = AllT.ToList().GetRange(Index, Count);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Ts = AllT.Skip(Index).ToList();
            }
            return Ts ;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Little different implementation with usage of circular buffer. The benchmarks show that the method is circa two times faster than ones using *Queue* (implementation of *TakeLast* in *System.Linq*), however not without a cost - it needs a buffer which grows along with the requested number of elements, even if you have a small collection you can get huge memory allocation.

```
public IEnumerable<T> TakeLast<T>(IEnumerable<T> source, int count)
{
    int i = 0;

    if (count < 1)
        yield break;

    if (source is IList<T> listSource)
    {
        if (listSource.Count < 1)
            yield break;

        for (i = listSource.Count < count ? 0 : listSource.Count - count; i < listSource.Count; i++)
            yield return listSource[i];

    }
    else
    {
        bool move = true;
        bool filled = false;
        T[] result = new T[count];

        using (var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
            while (move)
            {
                for (i = 0; (move = enumerator.MoveNext()) && i < count; i++)
                    result[i] = enumerator.Current;

                filled |= move;
            }

        if (filled)
            for (int j = i; j < count; j++)
                yield return result[j];

        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            yield return result[j];

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you use simplified enumrable like byte[] ,
you may want to use the SkipWhile()

on this example collecting the last 10 items:

```
myCollection.SkipWhile((item,index)=>i<=myCollection.Length-10)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
//detailed code for the problem
//suppose we have a enumerable collection 'collection'
var lastIndexOfCollection=collection.Count-1 ;
var nthIndexFromLast= lastIndexOfCollection- N;

var desiredCollection=collection.GetRange(nthIndexFromLast, N);
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

---

```
// use this one liner
var desiredCollection=collection.GetRange((collection.Count-(1+N)), N);
```

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer. However, code only answers are not very helpful. Please add a description of how this solves the OP's problem.

Comment: Also, when answering old, well answered questions, you have to explain what your answer adds to the existing answers. I wonder if you noticed [this existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23086131/861716) which basically does the same.