# Removing Lines from the textBox.

Tags: c#, winforms, serial-port

I am Reading data from serialport. I just want 40 lines to appear in the textbox.

How I can erase lines older lines to make Place for new lines?

I tried the following code:

```
     int numOfLines = 40; 
    var lines = this.textBox1.Lines;
    var newLines = lines.Skip(numOfLines);
    this.textBox1.Lines = newLines.ToArray();
```

But it gives me error, saying that " 'string[]' does not contain a definition for 'Skip' and no extension method 'Skip' accepting a first argument of type 'string[]' could be found".

Comment: Didn't you just asked the same some minutes ago? Add `using System.Linq;` to your class

Comment: @Pikoh Thanks :) I deleted that and came with a new question o show what code I have tried. "using System.Linq" did not work. same problem arise.

Comment: Do you have a reference in your proyect to `System.Core`? What .net platform target do you have?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have forgotten to add `using System.Linq;` directive

P.S. if you want last 40 lines to be appear, you can use approach described in this question: [Using Linq to get the last N elements of a collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3453274/using-linq-to-get-the-last-n-elements-of-a-collection)

Comment: `Take(n)` will give first n-elements. But not last n.

Comment: @LeonidMalyshev sorry, missed that question, will fix my post

Comment: same problem. saying that "using directive is unnecessary"

Comment: @user6203007 "using directive is unnecessary"..are you using Mono?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a reference to Linq:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: same problem. saying that "using directive is unnecessary"

Comment: Can you send me all the using directives in that files. Also what framework are you working with?

Comment: using System;
     using System.Collections.Generic;
     using System.ComponentModel;
     using System.Data;
     using System.Drawing;
     using System.Text;
     using System.Windows.Forms;
     using System.IO.Ports;
     using System.IO; 
     using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

Comment: try this and tell me what happens.......................  var newLines = System.Linq.Enumerable.Skip(lines, numOfLines);

Comment: It says the namespace name 'Linq' does not exist in the namespace 'System'.

Comment: @user6203007...i've already told you, add a reference to System.Core in your project

Answer (score 0):

`Skip` is a extension method of LINQ. You must add a reference to `System.Core` in your project, and in case it's needed a `using System.Linq;` directive

**Edit**

As you seem to be "unable" to use LINQ, here is a non-LINQ solution (just as an experiment of reinventing the wheel):

*Extension Methods*

```
public static class ExtMeth
{
    public static IEnumerable<string> SkipLines(this string[] s, int number)
    {
        for (int i = number; i < s.Length; i++)
        {
            yield return s[i];
        }
    }

    public static string[] ToArray(this IEnumerable<string> source)
    {
        int count = 0;
        string[] items = null;
        foreach (string it in source)
        {
            count++;
        }
        int index = 0;
        foreach (string item in source)
        {
            if (items == null)
            {
                items = new string[count];
            }
            items[index] = item;
            index++;
        }
        if (count == 0) return new string[0];
        return items;
    }
}
```

*Usage*

```
this.textBox1.Lines = this.textBox1.Lines.SkipLines(2).ToArray();
```