# Delete last N records, Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I use the following code to remove last N records in Entity Framework:

Extension method to take last N elements, taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3453301/4383472):

```
public static IEnumerable<T> TakeLast<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int N)
{
    return source.Skip(Math.Max(0, source.Count() - N));
}
```

Remove last N elements:

```
MyDbContext.MyDbSet.RemoveRange(MyDbContext.MyDbSet.TakeLast(N));
```

Is it effective? I do not want to reinvent the wheel. Maybe I missed some existing function like collection.RemoveLast (although I couldn't find one with my first effort)?

Comment: EF Provides `Remove` what to Remove is with respect to the requirement.

I think , The `TakeLast` will iterate through database to get last element , this is in efficient if you have large number of data. Skipping all the previous data is not sound good to me.

Ty something `TakeLast` where you get `DbSet.LastOrDefault` and Remove the item

Comment: @Eldho: In my case I want to remove not only last element, but last elements (several of them).

Comment: `RemoveRange` is okay but how do you get the last elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you have is ok. The `RemoveRange()` method is used to delete multiple items from the database. And the method you are using to get the last n items is okay as well. However `TakeLast()` will only return last items based on the order they were added to the database.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
var lastN = MyDbContext.MyDbSet
                       .OrderByDescending(g => g.Id)
                       .Take(N);

MyDbContext.MyDbSet.RemoveRange(lastN);
```

Comment: What if the Id is a GUID and not an integer?

Comment: Neither were specified in the question.

Comment: The extension method the OP has will work in any of the cases.