# How to take last records from list

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have list as follows

```
static List<MessageDetail> CurrentMessage = new List<MessageDetail>();
```

Dynamically, values assigned to this list for example:

```
CurrentMessage.Add(new MessageDetail { UserName = 123,GroupName = somegrp, Message = somemsg });
```

Here, I want to take last 5 or so records.

```
// this returns first 5 result, dont want to user orderby clause either
CurrentMessagesForGroup = CurrentMessage
                          .Where(c => c.GroupName == groupName)
                          .Take(5).ToList();
```

Is there a way to implement `TakeLast()` attribute? Or any kind of help will be appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Comment: If you don't want to use order by then how do you fix the last five entries?? By entry time or something else?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Linq to get the last N elements of a collection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3453274/using-linq-to-get-the-last-n-elements-of-a-collection)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`skip`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
CurrentMessagesForGroup = CurrentMessage
                    .Where(c => c.GroupName == groupName).Skip(Math.Max(0, CurrentMessage.Count() - 5)).ToList();
```

**EDIT**: I also find this that I think it is more easier to use ([MoreLinq](https://morelinq.github.io/)):

```
using MoreLinq;

var CurrentMessagesForGroup2 = CurrentMessage.TakeLast(5);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, exactly what i need.P1 for effort

Comment: @SuhailMumtazAwan Check my updated answer. I think it can be more simple if you use moreLINQ for this purpose.

Comment: @S.Akbari I'd personally link to https://morelinq.github.io, rather than a google project page. Also, TakeLast employs a Queue to reverse the order. Don't know how effective that is, I'm not good at big O notation. =)

Comment: @J.Steen Thanks. Updated.

Answer (score 3):

Use an OrderBy (ASC or DESC) to get the records lined up correctly for your Take operation.

**Ascending:**

```
CurrentMessagesForGroup = CurrentMessage
                        .Where(c => c.GroupName == groupName)
                        .OrderBy(c => c.GroupName)
                        .Take(5)
                        .ToList();
```

**or Descending:**

```
CurrentMessagesForGroup = CurrentMessage
                        .Where(c => c.GroupName == groupName)
                        .OrderByDescending(c => c.GroupName)
                        .Take(5)
                        .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but  as i already stated i dont want to use orderby clause .

Comment: I missed that in the comment. If you just want the last 5 added, then go with S.Akbari's answer, covered here as well  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3453274/using-linq-to-get-the-last-n-elements-of-a-collection

Answer (score 2):

If anyone using DotNet Core 2 or above or DotNet Standard 2.1 or above then you can use Linq's built in `.TakeLast()`

Reference: [Microsoft Documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.takelast?view=netcore-3.1)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Reverse()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358497(v=vs.110).aspx), which is slightly perverse.

```
CurrentMessagesForGroup = CurrentMessage
                    .Where(c => c.GroupName == groupName)
                    .Reverse()
                    .Take(5).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but this doesn't fullfil needs.P1 for effort

Comment: I'm curious - how doesn't it fulfil your need? I'd personally go with S. Akbari's answer myself, I'm just providing another option. =)

Answer (score 1):

I use an extension method for this.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> TakeLast<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int numElements)
{
    return source.Skip(Math.Max(0, source.Count() - numElements));
}
```

And to use it:

```
CurrentMessagesForGroup = CurrentMessage.Where(c => c.GroupName == groupName).TakeLast(5).ToList();
```

Edit: Credit to [Using Linq to get the last N elements of a collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3453301/1333655)

Answer (score 1):

I like this implementation, it uses a circular buffer.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> TakeLast<T>(this IEnumerable<T> input, int n)
{
    if (n == 0)
        yield break;

    int tail = 0;
    int head = 0;
    int count = 0;

    T[] buffer = new T[n];

    foreach (T item in input)
    {
        buffer[tail] = item;

        tail = (tail + 1) % n;

        if (count < n)
            count++;
        else
            head = (head + 1) % n;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        yield return buffer[(head + i) % n];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the MessageDetails class has numeric Id or Created date time we can use

```
var lastRecords= CurrentMessage.OrderByDescending(i=>i.Id).Where(p=>p.GroupName==groupName).Take(5).ToList();
```