# Get the last 3 items in a list with a foreach loop c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, loops

How do I get the last 3 items out of my list of images? I am using a `foreach` loop so i can get a single image and access its properties such as the `Url` for the img tag.

here is my code:

```
<div>
    @foreach (var image in Model.Images)
    {
        <img src="@image.Url" class="ArticleMainImage" />
    }
</div>
```

Comment: and . . . what is the question?

Comment: Is `Images` `IList<T>` or `IEnumerable<T>`?

Comment: how do i get the last 3 items of a list of something in a foreach loop

Comment: Images is a List<T>

Comment: `for(int i = Model.Images.Count - 4, i < Model.Images.Count; i++) { ... }` but why are you not just sending the correct list to the view in the first place?

Comment: does it have to be foreach? if you do a for-loop you could get the length and do something like `for(int i = length-3; i < length; i++) { list[i]... }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Model.Images.Reverse().Take(3).Reverse();
```

For Enumerable results -

```
 Model.Images.AsEnumerable().Reverse().Take(3).Reverse()
```

Found an extension method for suitability -

```
public static IEnumerable<T> TakeLast<T>(this IEnumerable<T> coll, int N)
{
    return coll.Reverse().Take(N).Reverse();
}
```

Source - https://stackoverflow.com/a/3453282/1982631

Comment: this is bad solution. This means you take all images to memory in the first reverse, than take first 3 and then that 3 items reverse. If it is List<T> and not enumerable, much better solution is use `for(int i = length-3; i < length; i++) { list[i]... }`

Answer (score 3):

Since `Model.Images` is a `List<Image>` you can simply access its `Count` property and index the last three elements in a `for` loop:

```
@for (int i = Model.Images.Count - 3; i < Model.Images.Count; i++)
{
    <img src="@Model.Images[i].Url" class="ArticleMainImage" />
}
```

Comment: How do i get the properties that at inside the list such as the **url**

Comment: @KyleBC I'm not sure I understand you... doesn't `Model.Images[i].Url` work? `Model.Images[i]` gives you the single image from the list at index `i`.

Comment: are you sure about the -4? count is not zero-based is it? so a count of 5, minus 3 = 2. i=2, which is the 3rd item, giving the 3rd, 4th and 5th.

Comment: @wazz omg you're right....I'll fix that...of course I want `Count-3`, `Count-2` and `Count-1`.

Answer (score 3):

Here is LINQ code that should take 3 last items if collection has more than 3 items. It doesn't do any sorting to keep images order intact. It just skips several first items.

```
<div>
    @foreach (var image in (Model.Images.Count > 3 ? Model.Images.Skip(Model.Images.Count - 3) : Model.Images))
    {
            <img src="@image.Url" class="ArticleMainImage" />
    }
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If images are a List, i think you can use:

```
List<Image> last3 = im.OrderByDescending(i => i).Take(3).ToList();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use for clause instead of foreach in order to control better the number of images you acquire from the list

```
<div>
@{
     @for(int i=0; i<= 3; i++)
     {
        if(i >= Model.Images.Count)
            break; //That in case your collection has less than 3 images
        var image = Model.Images[Model.Images.Count-i-1];
        <img src="@image.Url" class="ArticleMainImage" /> 
     } 
}
</div>
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.