# Grab last n items from C# list

Tags: c#

I have a C# `List<T>` of items. I want to iterate from a certain index to the end of the `List<T>` of items. Can I do this using the *foreach* syntax?

```
 List<T> list = ...

 foreach (var item in ???) 
 {
    ...
 }
```

or any other method?

e.g. from `List.Count - 50` until the end (I only want the *last* `50` items)

Comment: Have a look at linq and the Take() method

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Linq to get the last N elements of a collection?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3453301/969278)

Comment: _"or any other method?"_ What's wrong with a plain old `for` loop?

Comment: "What's wrong with a plain old for loop" - I want to learn better more modern ways.

Comment: `I want to learn better more modern ways` ...without doing any research myself

Comment: That's fine.  Keep in mind however that "better" and "more modern" aren't always synonymous.

Comment: The "modern way" is readable/maintainable code. I don't see that changing any time soon

Comment: @HarryBoy are you allergic to accepting answers

Answer (score 11):

Try:

```
foreach (var item in list.Skip(Math.Max(0, list.Count - 50)))
```

If you know the list will be at least 50 long, you can avoid the range checking:

```
foreach (var item in list.Skip(list.Count-50))
```

Although I'd DEFINITELY just write the for loop and avoid any fancy stuff:

```
for (int i = Math.Max(0, list.Count - 50); i < list.Count; ++i)
{
    // Do something with list[i]
}
```

Non-range-checked version:

```
for (int i = list.Count-50; i < list.Count; ++i)
{
    // Do something with list[i]
}
```

Comment: this one cost less resources

Comment: @Downvoter: It would be good to explain what is wrong with this answer.

Comment: The `AsEnumerable` method might be required, ex: `list.AsEnumerable().Skip...`. I don't know much about C# but I didn't find the `Skip` method with `list`.

Answer (score 7):

Try to use something like:

```
newList = Enumerable.Reverse(list).Take(50).Reverse().ToList();
```

Comment: this is costly, imagine if there is millions of items

Comment: @Fredou yes but it is just "any other method"

Answer (score 7):

Since `Skip` actually *enumerates* items, it's not very efficient in case of `List<T>`:

```
    public static IEnumerable<TSource> Skip<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, int count) {
        if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
        return SkipIterator<TSource>(source, count);
    }

    ...

    static IEnumerable<TSource> SkipIterator<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> source, int count) {
        using (IEnumerator<TSource> e = source.GetEnumerator()) {
            while (count > 0 && e.MoveNext()) count--;
            if (count <= 0) {
                while (e.MoveNext()) yield return e.Current;
            }
        }
    }
```

see reference source  http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,90ccdbd47b57182e
for details; if the initial list is *very long* one, I suggest using *for loop* and emulate *foreach* one:

```
// the simplest in case list.Count >= 50 
// foreach (var item in ...) {...} emulation
for (int i = list.Count - 50; i < list.Count; ++i) {
  var item = list[i];

  ...
}
```

For arbitrary size List  (can have fewer tan `50` items)

```
for (int i = Math.Max(list.Count - 50, 0); i < list.Count; ++i) {
  var item = list[i];

  ...
}
```

Comment: even better, no need for linq :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
myList.Reverse();          // Reverse the list
lastFive = myList.Take(5); // Take the first 5 elements from the list.
myList.Reverse();          // Restore the list to its original order.
```

Comment: this is costly, imagine if there is millions of items

Comment: OP did not specify cost or performance as an issue, in fact, explicitly said, "any other method".    Premature optimization is a huge problem, and my code is extremely simple.

Comment: it work, but in really bad scenario this code can cause out of memory

Comment: I think `lastFive` will still be in reverse order.

Comment: Then call `Reverse()` again.  My purpose is to instruct, not to provide a complete, perfect answer.

Answer (score 2):

Given that you have an `IList<T>` (assuming from your prose), then you can use a `for` loop to grab the last `n` pretty easily. This will still be lazily evaluated like much of LINQ -

```
public static IEnumerable<T> LastN<T>(this IList<T> list, int n)
{
    if (list == null) 
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("list");
    }

    if (list.Count - n < 0) 
    {
        n = list.Count;
    }

    for (var i = list.Count - n; i < list.Count; i++) 
    {
        yield return list[i];
    }
}

// use 
var tail50 = myList.LastN(50);
```

This will also well suited for an `ICollection<T>`.

There are some collection types that implement `ICollection<T>`, such as `LinkedList<T>`, that if you know about their concrete types, there may be more efficient ways to accomplish what you're needing. (in this case, the code above would be generally inefficient for a `LinkedList<T>`).

One thing to keep in mind when working with collections is `IEnumerable<T>` and the possibility that it's an infinite sequence. In those cases, unless you know the concrete type of the `IEnumerable<T>` or through other means know that it's finite, it's possibly best to re-think the idea of getting the "last n items", as it may not even be possible.

Comment: +1 Nice solution. Personnaly i would expect .LastN() to return the last n or, if there is less items, all the items.

Comment: I tend to agree with you, and adding another precondition invariant seems excessive anyhow.