# how to send an email for either the first and second or the last and pre last element of array

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop

I have an array of email addresses. I can send all email by using foreach(below).
How can i send email only for either the first and second or the last and pre last element in given array?

```html
string[] emails = storeEmails.Split(new char[] { ';' });

foreach (string emailTo in emails)
{
    emailTemplate.Email = emailTo;
    _eventService.SendEmail(emailTemplate, emailBody);
}
```

Comment: use the array indexes instead of a foreach loop

Answer (score 0):

You can do that easily with [Linq](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/getting-started-with-linq).

Here's an example (demonstrated using [xUnit](https://xunit.github.io)) of taking the first two:

```cs
using System.Linq;
using Xunit;

namespace Q54736241
{
    public class Example
    {
        [Fact]
        public void Example1()
        {
            var strings = new[] { "one", "two", "three", "four", "five" };

            var firstTwo = strings.Take(2);

            Assert.Equal(new[] {"one", "two"}, firstTwo);
        }
    }
}
```

You'll need to do a bit more work to get the last two. Check out this related question for some examples: [Using Linq to get the last N elements of a collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3453274/using-linq-to-get-the-last-n-elements-of-a-collection)