# C# TakeLast Extension for .Net Framework 4.6 and newer versions

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I'm looking for help finding an extension method for TakeLast that someone has written that can work for older versions of .Net Framework like 4.6 and higher. The default TakeLast method only works with my project for .Net 5 and .Net 6 but I'm trying to allow my program to be run on .Net Framework and the only thing I haven't been able to figure out is how to workaround the lack of TakeLast

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3453274/1911064) related question?

Comment: [MoreLinq.TakeLast](https://morelinq.github.io/2.4/ref/api/html/M_MoreLinq_MoreEnumerable_TakeLast__1.htm)

Comment: @AxelKemper No I didn't see that question before so thank you

Comment: Take care how you word your questions - how this is written is essentially  "find me a library that .." and is off topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement your own extension method, something like this:

```
public static partial class EnumearbleExtensions {
  public static IEnumerable<T> TakeLast<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int count) {
    if (null == source)
      throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
    if (count < 0)
      throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(count));

    if (0 == count)
      yield break;

    // Optimization (see JonasH's comment)
    if (source is ICollection<T>) {
      foreach (T item in source.Skip(((ICollection<T>)source).Count - count))
        yield return item;

      yield break;
    }

    if (source is IReadOnlyCollection<T>) {
      foreach (T item in source.Skip(((IReadOnlyCollection<T>)source).Count - count))
        yield return item;

      yield break;
    }

    // General case, we have to enumerate source
    Queue<T> result = new Queue<T>();

    foreach (T item in source) {
      if (result.Count == count)
        result.Dequeue();

      result.Enqueue(item);
    }

    foreach (T item in result)
      yield return result.Dequeue();
  }
}
```

Comment: Consider also adding a check if the source implements `ICollection`/`IReadOnlyCollection` and if so just use `.Skip(...)`

Comment: @JonasH that sounds like a great idea

Comment: @JonasH: thank you! Testing for `ICollection`/`IReadOnlyCollection` case is a valuable optimization

Comment: @DmitryBychenko This new version has an error if the item is an ICollection but the requested amount is higher than the source count and returns nothing except the expected action would be returning the source as is. For example if the source list has one item and it was asked to take the last 2 items, the result would be to return nothing

Comment: @DmitryBychenko This is the code I used to fix your version in case you are interested:

foreach (T item in source.Skip(Math.Max(0, ((ICollection<T>)source).Count - count)))
                yield return item;

Comment: @DarthVegan: Thank you! My bad, it should have been `count` subtracted: `((ICollection<T>)source).Count - count`: if we `Skip` negative value (say, `Skip(-10)`) it equals `Skip` nothing: `Skip(0)`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Oh for some reason I thought you would get an error if you tried to skip a negative number so I set my version to a minimum of 0 but either way your code is great so thanks