# ASP.NET Core WebApi Retrieve Last n Records

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core, webapi

I have put together a `GET` request that returns the last `n` (5) records on WebApi. Simply creating a call to get the entire list back async, then count the last five items, add them to a List of the custom type, that is `Application` in this case, then add then to a new list and return that.

Is there a more efficient way to run this query using Entity Framework core on .Net Core 6 webapi?

Here is my current code:

```cs
// GET: api/Application/last5
[HttpGet("last5")]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Application>>> Get5Applications()
{
    var list = await _context.Applications.ToListAsync();

    List<Application> returnedData = new List<Application>();

    for (int i = Math.Max(0, list.Count - 5); i < list.Count; ++i)
    {
        returnedData.Add(list[i]);
    }

    return returnedData;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Linq to get the last N elements of a collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3453274/using-linq-to-get-the-last-n-elements-of-a-collection)

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
_context.Applications.OrderByDescending(x => x.sortingproperty).Take(5);
```

System.Linq provides a Take function but it looks like you need to sort by decending order. You need to have some sort of property you're wanting to sort by. Replace sortingproperty with anything that fits your needs, normally an ID of some sort. I hope this helps. If you don't need the reversed order then you can use `_context.Applications.Take(5)`

Comment: you need to add an orderbydesc before take 5, he need last 5 record not the first 5 record

Comment: "You can also use TakeLast(n) if that better fits your needs." - I feel like that answers your point there.

Comment: TakeLast can't be translated to SQL, then is better orderbydescending then use take.

Comment: Ah okay. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get Last insert items. You can try 2 ways. I mentioned both of them followed photos. In this example I have product entity and I saved some items in database, then   tried both worked correctly. Also you can order by any column  if you  want. I ordered by id because it is auto increment

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ProductController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly AppDbContext _context;

    public ProductController(AppDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    [HttpGet("GetLastItems1/{take}")]
    public IEnumerable<Product> GetLastItems1(int take) => _context.Products
                                                                    .TakeLast(take)
                                                                    .ToList();

    [HttpGet("GetLastItems2/{take}")]
    public IEnumerable<Product> GetLastItems2(int take) => _context.Products
                                                                    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Id)
                                                                    .Take(take)
                                                                    .OrderBy(x => x.Id)
                                                                    .ToList();
}
```